# Chart.js line chart looking as area chart with smooth lines but not sharp

Tags: chart.js, linechart

The chartjs line chart is showing like an area chart and with smooth lines. I want to make the chart a simple line chart with sharp points. I have tried some options but all in vain.

```
var AreaChart = new Chart(AreaCharts, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Required',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#f39233',
        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
        hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
      },
      {
        label: '2nd',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#b8de6f',
        hoverBorderWidth: 2,

        hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    bezierCurve: false,
    scaleShowValues: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          padding: 10,
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: ''
    },
  },
});
```

This is the code. I am filling up the data and the labels from other function.
The line should be sharp and there should be just the line not any area. I did read the documentation but it is confusing for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have posted a solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/srux4971/

Most important parts are

```
data: {
            ...
            datasets: [{
                ...
                fill: false,   //no fill
                lineTension:0, //straight lines
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert the area chart into a line chart, add the option [`fill: false`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#line-styling) to each dataset.

I you also define the option `borderColor`, the lines will appear with the desired color.

Please take a look at your amended code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Required',
        data: [3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 4, 3],
        backgroundColor: '#f39233',
        borderColor: '#f39233',
        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
        hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: '2nd',
        data: [4, 1, 3, 5, 3, 4, 2],
        backgroundColor: '#b8de6f',
        borderColor: '#b8de6f',
        hoverBorderWidth: 2,
        hoverBorderColor: '#054564',
        fill: false
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    bezierCurve: false,
    scaleShowValues: true,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: true,
          padding: 10,
          fontSize: 10
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: ''
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="200"></canvas>
```